# How to "listen" for customtabsintent url?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, android-authenticator

I'm currently using xamarin.forms and xamarin.auth to authenticate users.
I am able to launch URL with CustomTabsIntent, however I am unable to figure out how to "listen" for the redirect URL. after user logs in, it just sits on the redirectURL page in the Custom Tab

How can I switch back to my android application when the customtabsintent made it to the redirectUrl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@SchwartzBrian 
You need concept called App (Deep) linking, basically

- register custom scheme with IntentFilter associated with Activity (in Xamarin.Android IntentFilter is Attribute on Activity)
- after login browser (CustomTabs) will inform OS that there is custom-scheme which cannot be handled by browser and OS will lookup registered schemes and packages (and Activities associated) that can handle this custom scheme. If Activity is 'found' OS will start it and pass the URL from browser to the Activity.OnCreate() method.

See:
https://github.com/moljac/Xamarin.Auth.Samples.NugetReferences/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms/Evolve16Labs/Droid/Xamarin.Auth/ActivityCustomUrlSchemeInterceptor.cs#L19-L48

Comment: I was able to get the deep linking working : see... https://stackoverflow.com/a/44377096/7685939