# Catching customurlscheme in android app?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, url-scheme

Currently using `CustomTabs/Native` UI with `Xamarin.Auth` to authenticate an Android application with Google through a custom web api ( I can not edit/change the web api). Is it possible to intercept a url (https) and return to the application once this url is reached? or will this not work with custom tabs due to chrome already being open?

Code for Intent Filter:

```
[
    IntentFilter
    (
        actions: new[] { Intent.ActionView },
        Categories = new[]
                {
                    Intent.CategoryDefault,
                    Intent.CategoryBrowsable
                },
        DataSchemes = new[]
                {
                    "https://redirectwebsite.com/"
                },
        DataPath = "https"
    )
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**
I was able to succussfully navigate back to my android app and grab the token information by changing my intent filter:

```
 [IntentFilter
    (
    actions: new[] { Intent.ActionView }, 
    Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault, Intent.CategoryBrowsable },
    DataSchemes = new[] { "https" }, 
    DataHost = "redirectwebsite.net",
    DataPath = "/", 
    AutoVerify = true
    )
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Brian don't we communicate on community slack?

Please save my butt. Context switching between slack (3 teams), forums, SO and github is kicking my butt all over the place and I'm not i7.

You have bunch errors in your code posted:

1. this is not DataScheme, but URL/URI/URN in DataScheme for this case it should be https only. But for native ui this is not right, because you need custom scheme.

`"https://redirectwebsite.com/"`

Yes there are tutorials where you can use http[s] on Android for deep linking (app linking), but I was not able to do it.

Please make minimal sample and make me happy to (to learn something).

Comment: Yes! we do communicate on the slack, I'm currently working through some tutorials on app linking (with no luck) I will post something on the slack if I can get it working

Comment: Cool. I tried it too, but could not waste too much time. I could not get http[s] scheme[s] to work. Maybe DataHosts and DataPaths could help filter it a bit better, but I think the problem is in scheme itself.